# Firestore Offline Persistence on the Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a little problem or you doubt Cloud Firestore in JavaScript.  The problem is this: I have a web application that will use or not, the offline persistence of Firestore that will be called by enablePersistence () until then ok, but I would like to know if there is any way I can find out if this persistence is already enabled  when my user comes back after a while, and if so how can I disable this persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to determine whether persistence is currently enabled. If you need to know whether it is, you'll have to store that somewhere yourself. For example, you could write the value into [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) when you enable/disable it, and read it from there.

Comment: But if I've already activated persistence, can you disable it later?

Comment: Oops, it seems like it's indeed not possible to disable persistence after enabling it. On Android/iOS this *is* possible, although I expect that there too you must set the correct value before accessing any data. You might want to see what happens if: 1) you call `enablePersistence()`, 2) you disable that call, 3) you reload the app.